# -webkit- doesn't work correctly on text-decoration

Tags: html, css, webkit, transition, underline

I have `transition` that fade in/out my underlined `text-decoration`. It works **perfectly** on every browsers, **except** on Safari that doesn't make the fade in/out transition.

I have added `-webkit-`, as indicated on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) to make it work on Safari, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem (and I can't use `border-bottom`).

Here is my CSS:

```html
.posts a:link {
  text-decoration: underline solid transparent;
  transition: text-decoration 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: text-decoration 0.3s ease;
}

.posts a:hover {
  text-decoration-color: black;
}
```

Comment: " Safari doesn't support text-decoration-style." which is part of the shorthand

Comment: @Paulie_D there is no "style" to my `text-decoration` since it is just `text-decoration: underline;`. How can I make the same `text-decoration: underline;` with the fade in/out working on Safari?

Comment: `text-decoration` **is** a shorthand. In CSS3, the text-decoration property is a shorthand property for text-decoration-line, text-decoration-color, and text-decoration-style.

Comment: So, my issue is radically not solvable?

Comment: Try just changing `text-decoration-color` on `hover`.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have updated my code. But doesn't seem to change anything…

Comment: Your second line of `text-decoration` will need to be deleted.

Comment: It is same result

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you know how to write code to get the same effect with `border-bottom`?